# .dll's are missing after rebuild/clean-build solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have 3 projects in my solution and a bunch of 3rd party or company dlls. Each time I rebuild my project or clean solution, a lot of this dll's are deleted, therefore missing. It is pretty annoying to reference this dll files again and again after rebuilding. Can someone explain how to avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have "referenced" them in your project and still they are missing ? or you just copied the dlls files to the output directory ?

Comment: Also in the properties menu (in the designer) for the references do they have "copy local" (that could be a reason why they are not in the folder if that is not set)

Comment: @Habib I created bin folder in the root folder, and copied there all dlls, then referenced them from this folder by references-add reference.

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov, there should already been a `bin` folder on your project's root folder

Comment: @Habib oh sorry it was there before, but it did not have my dll files. Also each of my project has bin folder, but I add references dll from my root bin. I am pretty confused why there are so much bin folders and how this references created and why they are disposed after each rebuild.

Comment: @Habib some of the bin folders have debug/release while other just have dll files.

Comment: Clean solution will remove all binaries in the bin folder. You need to refer it from actual location, every build will invariably copy them from to bin if that is the binary target folder

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `bin` folder is just the binary output from a build, so when you clean your solution, all the assemblies in the `bin` folder get deleted. You should reference the assemblies from some other location.  One suggestion is to create a `Shared Resources` folder within your project, copy your assemblies to that folder, then reference them from that folder.  This way they won't get deleted from `bin` on a clean/rebuild and Visual Studio will copy them there as needed.

1. Right-click on the `References` folder in your project and choose `Add Reference...`
2. Use the browse functionality to locate the assemblies you want to reference (don't worry about manually copying them to/from your `bin` folder)
3. After the reference is added, right-click on the reference in your references list and choose `Properties`
4. Make sure the `Copy Local` property is set to `True`

This will ensure that assembly is copied to your `bin` folder on every build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So actually when I clean/rebuild my sub-project, then bin folder within this sub-project will be emptied. If I rebuild the whole solution,will then bin folder in the root be deleted or every bin folder within sub-projects be emptied?

Comment: When you clean a project, the `bin` folder is emptied for that project.  There isn't a `bin` folder at the solution level, so when you clean the solution it will empty the `bin` folder for all projects within that solution.  I think Visual Studio has some special rules for which files/folders get deleted when performing a clean so there may be files leftover afterwards.  But the important thing is that the `bin` folder is the output of a build and you don't want to manually copy/reference your assemblies from there...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, .net framework version is the problem. I had to lower its version to 4.5 and then the projects got built properly and able to reference in other projects

Answer (score 0):

As Troy explained in his answer, indeed a reference to a `*.dll` file, kept outside the `bin` folder, ensures that the dll file does not get definitively wiped out when *cleanning* the project.

**However**, just by adding a reference to the assembly might not be enough. For instance it would **not work** for some other file types, such as the `*.pdb` files as well as for the `*.resources.dll` files (which are typically spread in many sub-folders named after the language codes (2 letters' language code)

To depict this problem with a real life situation, I picked up an assembly for which the source code is either gone, or not compatible anymore, etc. I chose (on purpose...) a 13 years old AjaxControlToolkit composed of many component files. The picture below illustrate its composition. Every time the "Clean" command is applied to the project all these files are deleted, except the one which is the referenced assembly. Moreover having several `*.resources.dll` file assemblies of the same name, as in the present case, makes it inconvenient, if not possible, to add "references" to each of them from within the same project.

[image]

Nevertheless here is a pretty **simple workaround**:

1. keep this file hierarchy in a separate folder (as Troy explained in his answer)
2. just copy them over in the `bin` folder using a command line entered in the Pre-build event of the project, such as `xcopy "$(SolutionDir)AjaxControlToolkit" "$(TargetDir)" /y /i /s /r /q`

[image]

Hoping that will be useful to someone...

---